# Limiting duplicate user input choices in consecutive If/Else

Tags: java, if-statement

How can I limit the user to spend a "Tag" on a different "Skill" on each inputFirstTag, inputSecondTag, inputThirdTag

Everything works fine until Round 2 rears its ugly head. inputSecondTag can become a duplicate of inputFirstTag, inputThirdTag can become a duplicate of inputSecondTag.

```
System.out.println("You have 3 Skills to Tag.");
        System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? (+25)");
        System.out.print("Small Guns, Big Guns, Energy Weapons, Unarmed, Melee Weapons, Throwing, ");
        System.out.print("First Aid, Doctor, Sneak, Lockpick, Steal, Traps, Science, Repair, ");
        System.out.println("Speech, Barter, Gambling or Outdoors?");
        Scanner scanFirstTag = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFirstTag = null;
        while (scanFirstTag.hasNextLine()) {
            inputFirstTag = scanFirstTag.nextLine();
            if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Small Guns") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Guns") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Energy Weapons") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Unarmed") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Melee Weapons") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Throwing") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("First Aid") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Doctor") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Sneak") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Lockpick") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Steal") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Traps") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Science") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Repair") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Speech") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Barter") ||
                    inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambling") || inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Outdoors"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Small Guns, Big Guns, Energy Weapons, " +
                    "Unarmed, Melee Weapons, Throwing, First Aid, Doctor, " +
                    "Sneak, Lockpick, Steal, Traps, Science, Repair, " +
                    "Speech, Barter, Gambling or Outdoors?");
        }
        if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Small Guns")) {
            System.out.println("Small Guns Increased by 25!");
            smallGuns = smallGuns + 25;
            System.out.println("Small Guns: " + smallGuns);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Guns")) {
            System.out.println("Big Guns Increased by 25!");
            bigGuns = bigGuns + 25;
            System.out.println("Big Guns: " + bigGuns);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Energy Weapons")) {
            System.out.println("Energy Weapons Increased by 25!");
            energyWeapons = energyWeapons + 25;
            System.out.println("Energy Weapons: " + energyWeapons);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Unarmed")) {
            System.out.println("Unarmed Increased by 25!");
            unarmed = unarmed + 25;
            System.out.println("Unarmed: " + unarmed);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Melee Weapons")) {
            System.out.println("Melee Weapons Increased by 25!");
            meleeWeapons = meleeWeapons+ 25;
            System.out.println("Melee Weapons: " + meleeWeapons);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Throwing")) {
            System.out.println("Throwing Increased by 25!");
            throwing = throwing + 25;
            System.out.println("Throwing: " + throwing);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("First Aid")) {
            System.out.println("First Aid Increased by 25!");
            firstAid = firstAid+ 25;
            System.out.println("First Aid: " + firstAid);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Doctor")) {
            System.out.println("Doctor Increased by 25!");
            doctor = doctor + 25;
            System.out.println("Doctor: " + doctor);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Sneak")) {
            System.out.println("Sneak Increased by 25!");
            sneak = sneak + 25;
            System.out.println("Sneak: " + sneak);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Lockpick")) {
            System.out.println("Lockpick Increased by 25!");
            lockpick = lockpick + 25;
            System.out.println("Lockpick: " + lockpick);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Steal")) {
            System.out.println("Steal Increased by 25!");
            steal = steal + 25;
            System.out.println("Steal: " + steal);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Traps")) {
            System.out.println("Traps Increased by 25!");
            traps = traps + 25;
            System.out.println("Traps: " + traps);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Science")) {
            System.out.println("Science Increased by 25!");
            science = science + 25;
            System.out.println("Science: " + science);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Repair")) {
            System.out.println("Repair Increased by 25!");
            repair = repair + 25;
            System.out.println("Repair: " + repair);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Speech")) {
            System.out.println("Speech Increased by 25!");
            speech = speech + 25;
            System.out.println("Speech: " + speech);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Barter")) {
            System.out.println("Barter Increased by 25!");
            barter = barter + 25;
            System.out.println("Barter: " + barter);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambling")) {
            System.out.println("Gambling Increased by 25!");
            gambling = gambling + 25;
            System.out.println("Gambling: " + gambling);
        } else if (inputFirstTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Outdoors")) {
            System.out.println("Outdoors Increased by 25!");
            outdoors = outdoors + 25;
            System.out.println("Outdoors: " + outdoors);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 2 Skills to Tag.");
        System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? (+20)");
        System.out.print("Small Guns, Big Guns, Energy Weapons, Unarmed, Melee Weapons, Throwing, ");
        System.out.print("First Aid, Doctor, Sneak, Lockpick, Steal, Traps, Science, Repair, ");
        System.out.println("Speech, Barter, Gambling or Outdoors?");
        Scanner scanSecondTag = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputSecondTag = null;
        while (scanSecondTag.hasNextLine()) {
            inputSecondTag = scanSecondTag.nextLine();
            if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Small Guns") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Guns") ||  inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Energy Weapons") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Unarmed") ||  inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Melee Weapons") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Throwing") ||  inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("First Aid") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Doctor") ||
                    inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Sneak") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Lockpick") ||
                    inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Steal") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Traps") ||
                    inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Science") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Repair") ||
                    inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Speech") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Barter") ||
                    inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambling") || inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Outdoors"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Small Guns, Big Guns, Energy Weapons, " +
                    "Unarmed, Melee Weapons, Throwing, First Aid, Doctor, " +
                    "Sneak, Lockpick, Steal, Traps, Science, Repair, " +
                    "Speech, Barter, Gambling or Outdoors?");
        }
        if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Small Guns")) {
            System.out.println("Small Guns Increased by 20!");
            smallGuns = smallGuns + 20;
            System.out.println("Small Guns: " + smallGuns);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Guns")) {
            System.out.println("Big Guns Increased by 20!");
            bigGuns = bigGuns + 20;
            System.out.println("Big Guns: " + bigGuns);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Energy Weapons")) {
            System.out.println("Energy Weapons Increased by 20!");
            energyWeapons = energyWeapons + 20;
            System.out.println("Energy Weapons: " + energyWeapons);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Unarmed")) {
            System.out.println("Unarmed Increased by 20!");
            unarmed = unarmed + 20;
            System.out.println("Unarmed: " + unarmed);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Melee Weapons")) {
            System.out.println("Melee Weapons Increased by 20!");
            meleeWeapons = meleeWeapons+ 20;
            System.out.println("Melee Weapons: " + meleeWeapons);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Throwing")) {
            System.out.println("Throwing Increased by 20!");
            throwing = throwing + 20;
            System.out.println("Throwing: " + throwing);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("First Aid")) {
            System.out.println("First Aid Increased by 20!");
            firstAid = firstAid+ 20;
            System.out.println("First Aid: " + firstAid);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Doctor")) {
            System.out.println("Doctor Increased by 20!");
            doctor = doctor + 20;
            System.out.println("Doctor: " + doctor);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Sneak")) {
            System.out.println("Sneak Increased by 20!");
            sneak = sneak + 20;
            System.out.println("Sneak: " + sneak);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Lockpick")) {
            System.out.println("Lockpick Increased by 20!");
            lockpick = lockpick + 20;
            System.out.println("Lockpick: " + lockpick);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Steal")) {
            System.out.println("Steal Increased by 20!");
            steal = steal + 20;
            System.out.println("Steal: " + steal);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Traps")) {
            System.out.println("Traps Increased by 20!");
            traps = traps + 20;
            System.out.println("Traps: " + traps);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Science")) {
            System.out.println("Science Increased by 20!");
            science = science + 20;
            System.out.println("Science: " + science);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Repair")) {
            System.out.println("Repair Increased by 20!");
            repair = repair + 20;
            System.out.println("Repair: " + repair);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Speech")) {
            System.out.println("Speech Increased by 20!");
            speech = speech + 20;
            System.out.println("Speech: " + speech);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Barter")) {
            System.out.println("Barter Increased by 20!");
            barter = barter + 20;
            System.out.println("Barter: " + barter);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambling")) {
            System.out.println("Gambling Increased by 20!");
            gambling = gambling + 20;
            System.out.println("Gambling: " + gambling);
        } else if (inputSecondTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Outdoors")) {
            System.out.println("Outdoors Increased by 20!");
            outdoors = outdoors + 20;
            System.out.println("Outdoors: " + outdoors);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("You have 1 Skill to Tag.");
        System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? (+15)");
        System.out.print("Small Guns, Big Guns, Energy Weapons, Unarmed, Melee Weapons, Throwing, ");
        System.out.print("First Aid, Doctor, Sneak, Lockpick, Steal, Traps, Science, Repair, ");
        System.out.println("Speech, Barter, Gambling or Outdoors?");
        Scanner scanThirdTag = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputThirdTag = null;
        while (scanThirdTag.hasNextLine()) {
            inputThirdTag = scanThirdTag.nextLine();
            if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Small Guns") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Guns") ||  inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Energy Weapons") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Unarmed") ||  inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Melee Weapons") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Throwing") ||  inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("First Aid") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Doctor") ||
                    inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Sneak") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Lockpick") ||
                    inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Steal") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Traps") ||
                    inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Science") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Repair") ||
                    inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Speech") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Barter") ||
                    inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambling") || inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Outdoors"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose Small Guns, Big Guns, Energy Weapons, " +
                    "Unarmed, Melee Weapons, Throwing, First Aid, Doctor, " +
                    "Sneak, Lockpick, Steal, Traps, Science, Repair, " +
                    "Speech, Barter, Gambling or Outdoors?");
        }
        if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Small Guns")) {
            System.out.println("Small Guns Increased by 25!");
            smallGuns = smallGuns + 25;
            System.out.println("Small Guns: " + smallGuns);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Big Guns")) {
            System.out.println("Big Guns Increased by 25!");
            bigGuns = bigGuns + 25;
            System.out.println("Big Guns: " + bigGuns);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Energy Weapons")) {
            System.out.println("Energy Weapons Increased by 25!");
            energyWeapons = energyWeapons + 25;
            System.out.println("Energy Weapons: " + energyWeapons);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Unarmed")) {
            System.out.println("Unarmed Increased by 25!");
            unarmed = unarmed + 25;
            System.out.println("Unarmed: " + unarmed);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Melee Weapons")) {
            System.out.println("Melee Weapons Increased by 25!");
            meleeWeapons = meleeWeapons+ 25;
            System.out.println("Melee Weapons: " + meleeWeapons);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Throwing")) {
            System.out.println("Throwing Increased by 25!");
            throwing = throwing + 25;
            System.out.println("Throwing: " + throwing);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("First Aid")) {
            System.out.println("First Aid Increased by 25!");
            firstAid = firstAid+ 25;
            System.out.println("First Aid: " + firstAid);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Doctor")) {
            System.out.println("Doctor Increased by 25!");
            doctor = doctor + 25;
            System.out.println("Doctor: " + doctor);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Sneak")) {
            System.out.println("Sneak Increased by 25!");
            sneak = sneak + 25;
            System.out.println("Sneak: " + sneak);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Lockpick")) {
            System.out.println("Lockpick Increased by 25!");
            lockpick = lockpick + 25;
            System.out.println("Lockpick: " + lockpick);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Steal")) {
            System.out.println("Steal Increased by 25!");
            steal = steal + 25;
            System.out.println("Steal: " + steal);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Traps")) {
            System.out.println("Traps Increased by 25!");
            traps = traps + 25;
            System.out.println("Traps: " + traps);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Science")) {
            System.out.println("Science Increased by 25!");
            science = science + 25;
            System.out.println("Science: " + science);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Repair")) {
            System.out.println("Repair Increased by 25!");
            repair = repair + 25;
            System.out.println("Repair: " + repair);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Speech")) {
            System.out.println("Speech Increased by 25!");
            speech = speech + 25;
            System.out.println("Speech: " + speech);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Barter")) {
            System.out.println("Barter Increased by 25!");
            barter = barter + 25;
            System.out.println("Barter: " + barter);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambling")) {
            System.out.println("Gambling Increased by 25!");
            gambling = gambling + 25;
            System.out.println("Gambling: " + gambling);
        } else if (inputThirdTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Outdoors")) {
            System.out.println("Outdoors Increased by 25!");
            outdoors = outdoors + 25;
            System.out.println("Outdoors: " + outdoors);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(enter);
        pressEnter.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your new Skills are:");
        System.out.println("Small Guns: " + smallGuns);
        System.out.println("Big Guns: " + bigGuns);
        System.out.println("Energy Weapons: " + energyWeapons);
        System.out.println("Unarmed: " + unarmed);
        System.out.println("Melee Weapons: " + meleeWeapons);
        System.out.println("Throwing: " + throwing);
        System.out.println("First Aid: " + firstAid);
        System.out.println("Doctor: " + doctor);
        System.out.println("Sneak: " + sneak);
        System.out.println("Lockpick: " + lockpick);
        System.out.println("Steal: " + steal);
        System.out.println("Traps: " + traps);
        System.out.println("Science: " + science);
        System.out.println("Repair: " + repair);
        System.out.println("Speech: " + speech);
        System.out.println("Barter: " + barter);
        System.out.println("Gambling: " + gambling);
        System.out.println("Outdoors: " + outdoors);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(enter);
        pressEnter.nextLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `switch` statement

Comment: That's a lot of code. Could you be more clear on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Have you thought about using reflection ?

Comment: MaxZoom & Alp, thank you for the suggestions, I am still learning Java & have not explored/learned switch and/or reflection yet. I will research these topics more. @Amaleemur, I'm trying to make it so the user can't input the same skill for 3 rounds in a row (Example: User picks Small Guns for inputFirstTag, inputSecondTag & inputThirdTag)

Comment: You could write this in a fraction of the code, by consolidating some of your very similar lines.  We can give you suggestions about how to do this on codereview.stackexchange.com, although these suggestions would be out of scope for StackOverflow.  Don't worry - you're doing great and we were there too.

Comment: La-comadreja, I really appreciate the offer and I will see you over there! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without overwhelming you with a long block of code:

You can create a Set data structure of "taggedSkills."  Initially, this Set is empty.  If the user tags a skill, the skill is added to the set.

Then if the user's second tag is the same skill as the first tag, the program can check the Set and ask the user to try again with a new skill, instead of adding a duplicate tag.  Same with the third skill.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, and I didn't feel like typing all the choices, but this might help you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Meow {

public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
        choices.add("Barter");
        choices.add("Repair");
        choices.add("Speech");
        choices.add("Potato");
        int[] numbers = new int[choices.size()];

    System.out.println("You have 3 Skills to Tag.");
    System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? (+25)");
    System.out.println("Barter, Repair, Speech, Potato?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputFirstTag = "";
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        inputFirstTag = scanner.nextLine();
        if ((choices.contains(inputFirstTag))){
            if(numbers[choices.indexOf(inputFirstTag)] == 0){
                numbers[choices.indexOf(inputFirstTag)] += 25;
                break;
            }
            else {System.out.println("Please don't choose duplicates");}
        }
        else {System.out.println("Please choose Repair, Speech, Barter.");}
    }

    System.out.println(inputFirstTag + " + 25");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("You have 2 Skills to Tag.");
    System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? (+25)");
    System.out.println("Barter, Repair, Speech, Potato?");
    String inputSecondTag = "";
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        inputSecondTag = scanner.nextLine();
        if ((choices.contains(inputSecondTag))){
            if(numbers[choices.indexOf(inputSecondTag)] == 0){
                numbers[choices.indexOf(inputSecondTag)] += 25;
                break;
            }
            else {System.out.println("Please don't choose duplicates");}
        }
        else {System.out.println("Please choose Repair, Speech, Barter.");}
    }
    System.out.println(inputSecondTag + " + 25");
    System.out.println();


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You have 1 Skill to Tag.");
    System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? (+25)");
    System.out.println("Barter, Repair, Speech, Potato?");
    String inputThirdTag = "";
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        inputThirdTag = scanner.nextLine();
        if ((choices.contains(inputThirdTag))){
            if(numbers[choices.indexOf(inputThirdTag)] == 0){
                numbers[choices.indexOf(inputThirdTag)] += 25;
                break;
            }
            else {System.out.println("Please don't choose duplicates");}
        }
        else {System.out.println("Please choose Repair, Speech, Barter.");}
    }

    System.out.println(inputThirdTag + " + 25");
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(choices.get(i) + " : " + numbers[i]);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Amaleemur, thank you very much, I have implemented your code and it is a good learning experience. Problem is now my output looks like this:
Small Guns : 0
Big Guns : 0
Energy Weapons : 0
Unarmed : 0
Melee Weapons : 0
Throwing : 0
First Aid : 25
Doctor : 25
Sneak : 0
Lockpick : 0
Steal : 0
Traps : 0
Science : 0
Repair : 25
Speech : 0
Barter : 0
Gambling : 0
Outdoors : 0

Comment: What's the problem with your output?

Answer (score 0):

My version.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SOFQuestion {

    private static Skill getSkillFromUser() {
        final Scanner scanFirstTag = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanFirstTag.hasNextLine()) {
            final String inputFirstTag = scanFirstTag.nextLine();
            for (Skill skill : Skill.values()) {
                if (skill.getSkillName().equalsIgnoreCase(inputFirstTag)) {
                    if (Skill.alreadyAddedSkills.contains(skill)) {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, but you have are already increased this skill.");
                        break;
                    }
                    return skill;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Please choose " + Skill.getSkillsList() + "?");
        }
        return null;
    }

    enum Skill {
        SMALL_GUNS("Small Guns"),
        THROWING("Throwing"),
        FIRST_AID("First Aid"),
        DOCTOR("Doctor");

        private final String skillName;
        private int skillPower;
        private static List<Skill> alreadyAddedSkills = new ArrayList<>();

        Skill(String skillName) {
            this.skillName = skillName;
        }

        public String getSkillName() {
            return skillName;
        }

        public int getSkillPower() {
            return skillPower;
        }

        public void increaseSkillPower(int skillPower) {
            this.skillPower += skillPower;
            alreadyAddedSkills.add(this);
            System.out.println("You increase " + getSkillName() + " skill to " + getSkillPower());
        }

        public static String getSkillsList() {
            final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (Skill s : Skill.values()) {
                if (alreadyAddedSkills.contains(s)) continue;

                sb.append(s.getSkillName()).append(", ");
            }
            if (sb.length() > 2) {
                return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 2);
            }
            return "EMPTY SKILL LIST";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int skillLimit = 3;
        int defPower = 10;
        while (skillLimit != 0) {
            final int powerToAdd = skillLimit * 5 + defPower;
            System.out.println("You have " + skillLimit-- + " Skills to Tag.");
            System.out.println("What skill would you like to Tag? " + "(+" + powerToAdd + ")");
            System.out.println(Skill.getSkillsList() + "?");

            final Skill skill = getSkillFromUser();
            if (skill == null) return;

            skill.increaseSkillPower(powerToAdd);
        }
        System.out.println("Your new Skills are:");
        for (Skill skill : Skill.values()) {
            System.out.println(skill.getSkillName() + ": " + skill.getSkillPower());
        }
    }
}
```